# Was the "Corporate Sector" part of the Republic?

Tags: star-wars

In [Attack of the Clones](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0121765/) Obi-Wan sees the officials from the 'Corporate Sector' and other factions meeting on Geonosis but later there is a map that shows it as a independent sector.  Did it succeed in exiting the Republic or was it not part of the Republic before the war?

The Corporate Sector is in the upper right of [this map](http://www.myconfinedspace.com/2011/04/20/map-of-the-star-wars-galaxy/starr-jpg/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [SW Wiki](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Corporate_Sector#cite_note-1):

> The Corporate Sector was first formed in 490 BBY to free the Republic lawmakers and the Corporate moneymakers from their differences, after being exiled from the Inner Rim to the Tingel Arm.
>
> The Corporate Sector originally had a few hundred systems all devoid of intelligent life.
>
> **The corporations allowed to operate in the sector could purchase entire regions of space, but were *supervised* by the Galactic Republic**

*(emphasis mine)*

It sounds like it wasn't a full-fledged part of the Republic, but was not 100% independent of it.

Comment: It sounds like it was basically unclaimed territory, owned by corporations within the republic.  Republic law therefore wouldn't be enforceable in those sectors.

Comment: A semi-autonomous region.

Comment: I've seen it described being a client state of the Empire.

Comment: @Phil - how is it a "state" in the first place?

Answer (score -1):

The Corporate Sector represents capitalism in its worst form. It operates independently and with out regard to human life or the good of beings.  It is supposed to be an evil entity with no redeeming qualities.  It is led by ugly greedy beings who seek power through use of droid slaves.

These corporations then team up with member states of the republic (Nemodians) to leverage the protection of the Republic and use the government to block the protection of the common being. They are the perfect villains as they use soulless droids to kill and slaughter low-tech creatures that literally have to climb out of the swamps to fight.  Their improbable victory is another David and Goliath story where a little boy saves the entire planet with a single stone... err photon torpedo.

In the sourcebooks and novels the Corporate Sector is often described as a lawless sector of space where smugglers can make good cred and criminals can go on the lam.